# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Tags: ios, facebook

i'm adding Facebook and Google signup in my application but i have this issue

> The operation couldn’t be completed. -10814

in the Facebook login and i don't know how to solve it, this is my app delegate code for the `openUrl`:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
        -> Bool {

            if let fbSDKAppId = FBSDKSettings.appID(), url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(fbSDKAppId)"), url.host == "authorize" {
            var shouldOpen :Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,  open: url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!,annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
            return shouldOpen
            }
            else {
                return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                     sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                     annotation: [:])
                }

            }
```

what i can do?

Comment: Try to add missing keys in info.plist

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani i just added it but it not work

Comment: When your app is crash?

Comment: 10814 occures when canOpenURL: not find your application Facebook. did you install Facebook ?

Comment: 10814 No application in the Launch Services database matches the input criteria.

Comment: @NazmulHasan i'm trying it on the simulator, i have to test it only on the device?

Comment: @bero Yea right! you have to test with real device or install Facebook to the simulator. best opinion try with real device

Comment: Try to update the SDK also check:  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/blob/master/Samples/Catalog/Sources/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: are you print the error for failure

Comment: ok thank you i try it now

Comment: which one are you tried it is in `FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount` or `web`

Comment: now I solved the issue ,try with once `loginBehavior as `web`

Comment: @bero - check the updated answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

now I used the latest SDK **v4.26.0** downloaded from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/) and I followed the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) for steps to install for FB. and my code is

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] <= 9) {
    // After iOS9 we can not use it anymore
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
} else {
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
}

NSArray *permission = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"email",@"public_profile",@"user_friends", nil];
NSLog( @"### running FB sdk version: %@", [FBSDKSettings sdkVersion] );

[login logInWithReadPermissions:permission fromViewController:(UIViewController *)self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    [self removeActivityIndicatorWithBg:activityIndicator];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Process error");
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Logged in%@",result.grantedPermissions);
    }
}];
```

here i used the login behavior as `FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount` and I get the error as

> (- error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. -10814)

so in my simulator or device contains no accounts setup in system settings for facebook. then it comes on the following block

```
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Process error");
}
```

if I print the error,

> **No Facebook account.
>   There are no Facebook accounts configured. You can add or create a Facebook account in Settings.**

so I changed the loginBehavior from  `FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount` to `FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb`, I got all OP with out error

Comment: Where exactly should I add the above code?

Comment: @huseyin - in your facebook login button action

Answer (score 2):

Worked after adding `openUrl` with options:

[Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios?sdk=cocoapods)

Note that `application:openURL:options:` is only available in `iOS 9` and above. If you are building with an older version of the `iOS SDK`, you can use:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, except for me I used Swift so I added

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:])

Answer (score 1):

`LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` property set in `info.plist` has solved the problem for me.
Check attached screenshot:

[image: info.plist]

Answer (score 0):

In this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/301) you can find an issue and a temporary fix for such kind of error.