# Facebook Login not working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, facebook, ios11, xcode9

We are currently Facing the Facebook Login issue in our iOS application on iOS 11. Facebook login working in iOS 10 but facing only this below issue in iOS 11. We also upgrade Facebook SDK to Latest version 4.24.0. 
When user perform FB login from App, then it required to Facebook on browser and perform login. After login, Facebook not redirect to Our Application. this issue occur only on ios 11.
From Browser Facebook not redirect to App on successfully login.

Comment: what the error u faced on

Comment: Its not giving error. After Login , Facebook not automatically redirect to Application. Its show blank white page on browser with done button in navigation

Comment: see this may be u faced this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319937/canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-osstatus-error-10814/46321192#46321192

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Issue is resolve by Enabling Key Chain Access in App. Its only happen on iOS 11.

Comment: @Hiren How can we enable 'Key Chain Access' in our App ?