# iOS 11 Simulator dont open facebook login in safari - Cordova Facebook4

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, cordova, safari

I have a Cordova APP and the login is based using [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4).

This plugin opens safari browser to make login. After update xcode to version 9.0, the simulator was updated to iOS 11, and facebook don't open in safari browser and show this message

> Safari cannot open the page because it could not establish a secure
>   connection to the server.

I tryed clear browsing cache but don't works, excepted that the previous version of iOS simulator works. (version 10)

Comment: It happens because Apple will not allow using system accounts for Facebook and Twitter. I don't know how it works on Cordova but native solution you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46321192/1067147

Comment: I had the same issue, but for me, not just the cordova apps. Even using just the safari and opening facebook or twitter, it hows unsecure connection, but other sites just fine. I can even open youtube.

Answer (score 4):

I have same issue.
I have avast antivirus.
I made some changes in avast antivirus

open Avast -> Preferences -> Shields -> Web shield -> settings
and add server
*.facebook.com        https

and it is working now.