# iOS: -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)" on Simulators & Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios-simulator

I used that [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/) but I have that error message. Impossible to know why. What I want is to have just a button, click on it to share a local image on an iPad, without having the facebook app installed. I just want the user click on the button, enter his login/password, post it, and that's all.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."];

FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = image;
photo.userGenerated = YES;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];
```

openUrl method in appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
    NSLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
    NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
    NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
    NSLog(@"url path: %@", [url path]);

      return YES;
}
```

I precise that there is a problem on the line:

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

- that do an other message error in the console (simulator):
  **Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug

  Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug**
- thant do an other message error in the console (device):
  **Task .<1> finished with error - code: -1001**

For info, here is my plist keys:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fb2000xxxxxxxxxxx</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>com.newTelApps.WebBoxEssaisPresse</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>2000xxxxxxxxxxx</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>WebBox</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>twitter</string>
    <string>facebook</string>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
</array>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this for e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319937/canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-osstatus-error-10814/46321192#46321192

Comment: have you added openURL method in AppDelegate?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried, but the same error occurs.

Comment: @Raj Yep, I updated my stackoverflow ticket with my openUrl method to show you

Comment: Facebook is no longer integrated in iOS 11 that's why FBSDKShareDialog works only if the native Facebook app is installed on the device. Do you have that error on iOS 11 or prior?

Answer (score 0):

go to `Info.plist` and change
`App Transport Security Settings` ==> `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to  `YES`

or

add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`

Comment: Hi, I already put that keys, a few others. I updated my ticket to show you