# Cannot share link to facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am working with Xcode 9 and Swift 4.0. I need to share a link to Facebook when clicking a button. I have integrated Facebook SDK.I have completed all the steps mentioned in Facebook documentation. But i can't share the link to facebook. My code is given below.
It shows the error

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

```
    if(FBSDKAccessToken.current() .hasGranted("publish_actions"))
    {
        self.postToFacebook()
    }
    else
    {
        let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        login.logIn(withPublishPermissions: ["publish_actions"], from: self) { (result, error) in

            if (error != nil) {
                print("publish_actions: \(error!)")
            } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
                print("publish_actions: Canceled")
            } else if (result?.grantedPermissions.contains("publish_actions"))! {
                print("publish_actions: permissions granted: \(String(describing: result?.token.tokenString))")
                self.tokenString = "\(String(describing: result?.token.tokenString))"
                self.postToFacebook()
                //UserDefaults.standard.set(result?.token.tokenString, forKey: "facebook_token")

            }
        }
    }
}`

 func postToFacebook()
{
    do{
        var myContent = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/8MinuteWorkoutChallenge")!)
        myContent.hashtag = Hashtag("#8MWC")

        let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: myContent)
        shareDialog.mode = .native
        shareDialog.failsOnInvalidData = true
        shareDialog.completion = { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                print("Share succeeded")
            case .failed:
                // self.shareButton.isHidden = true
                print("failed")
            case .cancelled:
                print("Share cancelled")
            }
        }

        try shareDialog.show()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Comment: see this once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319937/canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-osstatus-error-10814/46321192#46321192

Answer (score 1):

`OSStatus error -10814` (aka `kLSApplicationNotFoundErr`) occurs when an application cannot be found in the Launch Service's database. In other words, iOS cannot find an app with the scheme `fbauth2`...It looks like you don't have Facebook installed on your test device :)

Ref: https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=10814

Comment: That is, the share functionality will not work if there is no facebook application in the device. right?

Comment: I’m not particularly familiar with the Facebook SDK and it’s inner workings, but from the looks of things, in your situation, the Facebook app is required for at least authentication purposes.