# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fbauth2" (OSStatus error -10814.)

Tags: ios, facebook, ios10

This error message when I try to login:_

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

I have macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.
My Xcode version is 9.4.1.

SDKs iOS 10.2, Simulator

I have tried mothod but doesn't help:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

I also did try to play around `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` but not success as well.

Comment: It's on iPhone or the simulator? Is `Facebook` app installed?

Comment: it's on Simulator 
Facebook app is not installed on the Simulator

Comment: you can refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319937/canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-osstatus-error-10814

Comment: i have see it before but still not working

Comment: Did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46321192/5492956 ? The same error occurred there.

Comment: yes I did, i tried many times i dont know whats wrong

Comment: You're are testing in the simulator. You need to test on a real device with the Facebook app installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" (OSStatus error -10814.)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319937/canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-osstatus-error-10814)

Answer (score 5):

The same issue I resolved it by adding this in `Info.plist`

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
</array>
```

You need to set it according to your **SDK** version.

**More detail refer [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) Document.**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error followed by the logs that tells *Unable to communicate with the source application* , When we are using the IOS simulator and Facebook is not installed on Simulator then the Source app is meant by the Safari App. Because in that case the Facebook SDK will load the safari or the default browser for the user to Login through Facebook.
I observed that opening safari on the chosen simulator was not coming up, so I had to wait until the safari is working fine on Simulator then doing it with my app on the simulator the login was successful.