# Facebook login setup failure

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I've gone through the Facebook "Quickstart" guide multiple times but can't seem to figure out what is causing this error. I'm trying to authenticate through FB using the following function call:

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in

}
```

However, I'm getting the following error console output:

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Here are my AppDelegate methods:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance()!.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance()!.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

I've added the following key/values to my `Info.plist` as told by the Quickstart guide:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb719997618357318</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>719997618357318</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>Test</string>

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319937/canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-osstatus-error-10814/46321192#46321192

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this didn't help solve the issue :(

Comment: Known bug: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/301

Comment: The message you mentioned, it's a warning not an Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the Facebook SDK due to the recent Xcode 10.1 update. The function signatures for `UIApplicationDelegate` have changed slightly:

```
// before
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
// before
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

The key change is that the `options` dictionary is no longer keyed by `String` types. Instead, the keys are typed as `UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey`, which have the following definition:

```
// Inside definition of `UIApplication`
public struct OpenURLOptionsKey : Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {

    public init(rawValue: String)
}
```

---

The solution right now is to target a specific version of the Facebook SDK discussed by this thread: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/301.

Answer (score 0):

@Kelvin Lua

You need to implement this method in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool{

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application (
        application,
        open: url as URL!,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
}
```

This method will be called when user logged in form the Application. Just try it and let me know if it works or not else will try to help you out with something else.