# Swift Facebook Auth with firebase canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Tags: ios, swift

i try to implement facebook auth with firebase at my swift app. Unfortunately i receive this error

> canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

It doesnt matter if i try it with a simulator or a physical phone.

Here is my App Delegate code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance()?.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

and here is my ViewController code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 50, width: view.frame.width-30, height: 50)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.s


}


  func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }else{
        print("worked")
    }
}

 func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("logged out")
}
```

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319937/canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-osstatus-error-10814/46321192#46321192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently face the same issue in one of my project in which I have updated Swift version to 4.2 from 4.0

This issue is from Facebook 4.39.0 Pod frameworks.

FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit for 4.39.0 version is not working, so whenever you update your code to Swift 4.2 then kindly mention your code with specified version.

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.38.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.38.1'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.38.1'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I've got the same issue but using swift 5 - these versions are outdated for that as I get  the error
    FirebaseUI was resolved to 8.4.2, which depends on
    FirebaseUI/Facebook (= 8.4.2) was resolved to 8.4.2, which depends on
    FBSDKLoginKit (~> 5.0)
But FBSDKLoginKit version 5 having the same error as above. Do you know if theres a workaround here?