# How to fix (-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)") issue

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am using Xcode Version 10.2.1, and Swift 5 and I wanted to implement FaceBook login into my app. I followed care-full FaceBook SDK quick start but unfortunately I am getting this error.

There are many forms and discussions about this and even answers but none of them worked for me.

Can you explain why I am getting this error and how to fix?

Here is my code in `info.plist`

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb367273353954868</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>367273353954868</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>LookTV</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Can you put your Info.plist file and full error log?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/301 This issue seems to be closed , have you tried the things as mentioned?

Comment: see this for help : [-canOpenURL: failed for URL: “fbauth2:/” (OSStatus error -10814.)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319937/canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-osstatus-error-10814/46321192#46321192)

Comment: @Vizllx I tried everything in that link but no help

Comment: did you ever solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: I uninstalled the Facebook API and cleared the project folder then re started it worked