# FBSDK not working in Swift getting -canOpenURL: failed for URL?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i am trying to integrate FB login below is but getting error as `-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbapi:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"`

I should get all value ex. email, profileData, token

Below is my code

```
 func signInWithFacebook(){
        print("----- FB Sign-In -----")
        var email = ""
        manager.logIn(
            permissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: nil) { (result, err) in
                
                if err != nil{
                    print(err!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "email, id"])
                request.start { (_, res, err) in
                    guard let profileData = res as? [String: Any] else {return}
                    if let emailValue = profileData["email, id"] as? String {
                        email = emailValue
                        
                        print("----- FB email -----\(email)")
                        print("----- FB profileData -----\(profileData)")
                        var token = AccessToken.current?.tokenString ?? ""
                        print("----- FB email -----\(token)")
                        
                        
                        // after we receive data from FB
                        // send it to our server and receive the user model
                        // below is the code
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" (OSStatus error -10814.)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319937/canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-osstatus-error-10814)

Comment: @ohglstr not really

Comment: You should show exactly how you are setting up the SDK.